# MYSQL Using grouped values to create another column

Tags: mysql

I have a table I am trying to use two aggregate values to create another column. For example

My table looks like this

```
| id | col_a | col_b
---------------------
| 1 |      5 |    10
| 1 |     15 |    20
| 2 |      1 |     2
| 2 |      3 |     4
| 2 |      5 |     6
```

And I want the output to be

```
| id | total_a | total_b | grand_total
---------------------------------------
|  1 |      20 |      30 |          50
|  2 |       9 |      12 |          21
```

And I tried

```
SELECT id, 
SUM(col_a) AS total_a,
SUM(col_b) AS total_b,
(total_a + total_b) AS grand_total
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id
```

But that gives me an error `Unknown column 'total_a' in 'field list'`

I also tried using variables like this, but I don't think I am using variables correctly here.

```
SELECT id, 
@a := SUM(col_a) AS total_a,
@b := SUM(col_b) AS total_b,
(SELECT @a + @b) AS grand_total
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id
```

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like this should be simple.

Comment: you should repeat each sum aggregation for both columns  individually such as `(SUM(col_a)+SUM(col_b)) AS grand_total`, the calcuated columns can only be used after been  derived from a subquery.

Comment: Yup, just figured that out and felt like a fool. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured it out. It *is* in fact really simple

```
SELECT id, 
SUM(col_a) AS total_a,
SUM(col_b) AS total_b,
(SUM(col_a) + SUM(col_b)) AS grand_total
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id
```